# React Native - xhr.upload.onprogress showing inaccurate result

Tags: react-native, expo, xmlhttprequest

I am using xhr to upload images and videos in a React Native mobile app (currently only tested on Android).

The actual upload works correctly however the `xhr.upload.onprogress` callback is reporting inaccurate data.  For example, when uploading a large file (~70mb) this returns 0%, then 69%, then 98%, then 100% - this is returned over the first few seconds even though the actual file upload takes ~1-2 minutes.

Here is my code:

```
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("FileInput", {
          uri: uri,
          type: "video/" + ext,
          name: fileName,
        });

          const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

          xhr.open("POST", url);
      
          xhr.onload = () => {
            const response = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
            resolve(true);
          };
          xhr.onerror = (e) => {
            console.log(e, "upload failed");
          };
          xhr.ontimeout = (e) => {
            console.log(e, "upload timeout");
          };

          xhr.send(formData);

          if (xhr.upload) {
            xhr.upload.onprogress = ({ total, loaded }) => {
              uploadProgress = Math.round((loaded / total) * 100);
              console.log(uploadProgress, total, loaded);
            };
          }
```

Any pointers to what might be going on here would be really appreciated.

***UPDATE**: I have also implemented this upload using axios and get exactly the same issue where the onUploadProgress reports 100% very quickly even though the actual upload takes much longer.*

```
const config = {
      onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
            uploadProgress = Math.round(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100;
            console.log(uploadProgress);
          },
      headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
        };
    
const upload = await axios.post(url, formData, config);
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I've figured this out.  Just in case this helps someone else:

The issue was occurring when running a development bundle on a metro server - axios/xhr was reporting on the status of the upload of the file to the metro proxy rather than to it's final destination on the net.

When I created an apk build everything was working correctly.